# Create a HaarCascade to output percentages instead of outputting a "true" when a threshold is being surpassed

Tags: c#, face-detection, face-recognition, aforge, accord.net

My goal is to use my webcam to capture my face and detect my mood by facial expression. The output should be probabilites like 70 % happy, 10 % sad, ...

My approach: very happy and very sad ( and other states ) faces should be saved in a HaarCascade.

My problems are twofold:

1. How do I create a HaarCascade to use with HaarObjectDetector for the
   HaarObjectDetector object to output percentages instead of
   outputting a "true" when a threshold is being surpassed?
2. How do I create a HaarCascade for HaarCascade? Is it easier to use `String path = @"C:\Users\haarcascade-frontalface_alt2.xml"; HaarCascade cascade1 = HaarCascade.FromXml(path);` with opencv-xml or generate it using `HaarCascade m = new HaarCascade(20,20,HaarCascadeStages);`? What would HaarCascadeStages be?

Have others already solved this issue and offer sourcecode for c#?

My current code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool DeviceExist = false;
    private FilterInfoCollection videoDevices;
    private VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = null;
    Bitmap picture;

    HaarObjectDetector detector;
    FaceHaarCascade cascade;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // get the devices name
    private void getCamList()
    {
        try
        {
            videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            if (videoDevices.Count == 0)
                throw new ApplicationException();

            DeviceExist = true;
            foreach (FilterInfo device in videoDevices)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(device.Name);
            }
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0; //make dafault to first cam
        }
        catch (ApplicationException)
        {
            DeviceExist = false;
            comboBox1.Items.Add("No capture device on your system");
        }
    }


    //toggle start and stop button
    private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    //eventhandler if new frame is ready
    private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        picture = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        //Rectangle[] objects = detector.ProcessFrame(picture);
        //if (objects.Length > 0)
        //{
        //    RectanglesMarker marker = new RectanglesMarker(objects, Color.Fuchsia);
        //    pictureBox1.Image = marker.Apply(picture);
        //}
        pictureBox1.Image = picture;

    }

    //close the device safely
    private void CloseVideoSource()
    {
        if (!(videoSource == null))
            if (videoSource.IsRunning)
            {
                videoSource.SignalToStop();
                videoSource = null;
            }
    }

    //get total received frame at 1 second tick
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = "Device running... " + videoSource.FramesReceived.ToString() + " FPS";
    }

    //prevent sudden close while device is running
    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        CloseVideoSource();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getCamList();
        cascade = new FaceHaarCascade();
        detector = new HaarObjectDetector(cascade, 30);
        detector.SearchMode = ObjectDetectorSearchMode.Average;
        detector.ScalingFactor = 1.5f;
        detector.ScalingMode = ObjectDetectorScalingMode.GreaterToSmaller;
        detector.UseParallelProcessing = false;
        detector.Suppression = 2;
    }

    private void rfsh_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void start_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (start.Text == "Start")
        {
            if (DeviceExist)
            {
                videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
                videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
                CloseVideoSource();
                videoSource.DesiredFrameSize = new Size(640, 480);
                //videoSource.DesiredFrameRate = 10;
                videoSource.Start();
                label2.Text = "Device running...";
                start.Text = "Stop";
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                label2.Text = "Error: No Device selected.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (videoSource.IsRunning)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                CloseVideoSource();
                label2.Text = "Device stopped.";
                start.Text = "Start";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the usual way of solving this problem is to separate the face detection part from the expression detection part. For example, first you would use the Haar detector to detect a face. Then you would crop it from the rest of the image and apply another classifier to get whether it is a sad or happy face.

Comment: But regarding the question, unfortunately the algorithm to "learn" a cascade isn't available in Accord.NET but only in OpenCV. There are other classifiers that you can use, though. In the past I have used SVMs for a very similar task with good results. I can post an answer describing how to do this.

Comment: @Cesar "I think the usual way of solving this problem is to separate the face detection part from the expression detection part. For example, first you would use the Haar detector to detect a face. Then you would crop it from the rest of the image and apply another classifier to get whether it is a sad or happy face." That's what I did. I noticed, that it slowed down the process significantly, even on 160 x 120 images. For the facial expression classifier in opencv, what do you use as negative images?